# Refreshing updated question in mobile version

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

In Android SO app, after a question you are looking at has been updated, we get a footer message stating as much.  This footer also has what seems to be a "Refresh" icon (two circular arrows).

This icon does not seem to be *live*. Pushing it does not have any effect. The only way to see the updated version is to exit the question and then select it again.

If this is indeed the case (I'm not missing something obvious) I would like to request assigning the actual action to this icon.

Comment: I'm not sure what button you're referring to, but you can pull/swipe up to refresh.

Comment: @hichris123 - Just to clarify: this is about a singular question (not a list of questions).

Comment: Yeah, you can still pull/swipe up to refresh on a single question.

Comment: @hichris123 - I tried it today but the footer with `↺` does not disappear until I exit and re-enter the question view screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what's going on here is that the *entire bar* showing "Post has been edited" is clickable, and you can click (err, tap) on it to refresh the page. Apparently making the entire view clickable didn't make the *button* clickable too, so as of version 1.0.53 (releasing to beta users later today) the button will also be clickable.

Comment: I am using `1.0.53`.  Do I understand correctly that once I "*click*" anywhere on the bar (including the icon itself) the question view will be updated and the bar disappear?

Comment: Yes, it has been fixed.